# how to adjust a render to match the 3d view?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blender-internal-render-engine

I have a beautiful soccer ball model and it looks great in the 3d ortho - edit views. I love it! 
[image]
But when I go to use the renderer - Blender Render comes up blank and Cycles render looks like this. Not so sharp, filling with dots of white. Not sure what happened. What can I do to adjust it to match how it looks in when I edit it?

[image]

Comment: What is your lighting set up? What are your Cycles render settings, especially under the sampling tab? But whatever they are, it's likely you can get a result you are happy with simply by turning on Denoising. Check the box in the Denoising section of the Properties > Scene tab, usually it is at the bottom.

Comment: If you want your render to look like the viewport, simply render the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the amount of noise in an image rendered by Cycles, you can do the following:

### Turn up your samples

- Under the Sampling section of the Render tab, you can adjust the number of render samples.
- Increasing the samples will increase your render time proportionally, but you will get cleaner images.

### Turn on denoising

- As @kim-holder mentioned, you can turn on denoising to reduce the noise in the image. This is a new feature added to Cycles in 2.79
- This will usually do a good job of getting rid of noise, but often softens the image and blurs edges to a certain extent.

### Dim the lights

- It may also be that your lights are set to be too intense. Lowering their intensity should help to reduce fireflies (the bright white spots on your image)

### Turn on "Filter Glossy"

- Filter Glossy reduces fireflies on glossy surfaces by blurring them slightly. See [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/cycles/settings/scene/render/integrator.html#render-cycles-integrator-filter-glossy) for more information.